# Kerberos Authentication Breaks with Java 8

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas

New to this forum and am not the original developer of the product....

We have a custom built SSO solution that uses Tomcat, Kerberos, Windows Server 2008, AD, Java 1.7 and JAAS. The program works correctly running Oracle Java 7.1_045 64bit. We are being forced to move to 1.8.0_45 64 bit. I installed Java 1.8 and recompiled the code with no issue. But now the call to authenticate the Ticket is failing without a lot of error messages. I have narrowed down the code that fails to the following:

```
try {
    GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    GSSContext context = manager.createContext((GSSCredential)null);
    context.acceptSecContext(serviceTicket, 0,serviceTicket.length);
    GSSName clientGSSName = context.getSrcName();
    return clientGSSName;
} catch (GSSException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(exp);
  }
}
```

I know this is not a lot to go on but I am hoping that this is something somebody else has experienced.

Thank you for any inpput.

Comment: "failing without a lot of error messages" leads me to wonder are there any error messages?

Comment: Errors ocuring in this place are very configuration-dependent. Could you attach your krb5.ini file and file containing your JAAS configuration? Could you run application with JVM parameters -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.jgss.debug=true, gather logs and attach error message?

Comment: About the new Oracle JRE: was it a vanilla install, or did you also download the "unlimited strength crypto" JARs? That could explain some specific error messages. But since you don't want to share the error messages, anyway...

Comment: I was not clearer in my first posting. The error is received when the GSSName clientGSSName = context.getSrcName() is made. It is returing NULL. This is a vanilla install of Java 1.8. I did turn on logging which produced a ton of messages but do not believe I can post them to this forum. Maybe there is something specific I can look for in the log files?

Comment: Here is a part of the krb.ini krb5.ini: [libdefaults]
default_realm = <my realm>
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
forwardable=true

Comment: Here is the JAAS file:

SSO {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=false
storeKey=true
useTicketCache=false
principal="$myprincipal" ;
};

Comment: Solved: The issue is with the build of Java 1.8. There is a bug in 1.8.0_45 that specifically deals with SPNEGO/Kerberos authentication. Downgrading to _31 or upgrading to _51 fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you Frankie point to the Bug number/ticket about SPNEGO/Kerberos?. I suffered something on my laptop after installing Java8. After doing that, I was unable to login to any Kerberos secured Web-UI we have (we are working with Hadoop). Then I were unable to find a solution and asked to re-stage the whole laptop. Of course that made it work back again. During my investigation I saw that all my web browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome) switched to send NTLM security context instead of SPNEGO one. Unfortunatelly I uninstalled any Java 8 reference without success to my problem.